Gate driver power supply design simplification
Looking at many reference 3 phase inverter designs given by reputed manufacturers(such as TI, Infineon, Toshiba etc), they design every aspect of the gate driver power supply. (Using pulse transformers, rectifiers or flyback converters.) It sounds like a lot of unnecessary hassle to get the required galvanic isolation.
Look at this example from Infineon, Link:

OR this design by TI, Link:

Both of these use some form of flyback or forward converters to generate the required voltage levels.
Wouldn't it be better/Cheaper/Space saving/less complicated to just use ready made isolated DC/DC converters available in small SIP designs from known OEMs such as Recom or Murata Example Link?

What are the Pros and Cons of the above mentioned gate drive power supply design methodologies?

If an off-the-shelf converter solves your problems, and your application can carry the cost, then by all means buy the off-the-shelf brick.

The input to output capacitance may be relevant.

Of your concerns, cheaper is the strongest motivation, so let's consider that.
Cost
The RKZE-1212S is currently $6.62/100s at Digikey.
Suppose we need four or six to implement an H- or Ж-bridge for industrial power or motor control.  This increases the BOM cost by $26-40.
(Signal isolators and gate drivers are needed regardless, so contribute no cost differential here.  There are some knock-on products, like Analog Devices' isoPower series.  Discrete isolators and drivers, or combination isolator-drivers like NCD57084DR2G or HCPL-316J, may offer other tradeoffs as well, though unrelated to the DC-DC function.)
Compare to a multi-winding transformer, which can be custom designed (tailored to the application) for about the same cost in this quantity, but we would only need one or two.
Or, a planar transformer can be constructed, using a set of ferrite cores e.g. TDK ELP14/3.5/5 clamped around windings formed in the PCB itself.  If the PCB is already multilayer (at least 4 layers, but for this, 6-8 layers might be practical), this adds very little cost; if not, a set of planar windings can be made in small PCB "stackers", and the overall transformer (windings and core) glued together, pins soldered or pressed in, and used as a packaged part.
The transformer may be one of the larger costs, but it's not the only one.  We have to consider the power source, switching regulator/controller.  I won't go into detail here, as very cheap ones of adequate ratings are readily available (offhand: NCP3063, CS/NCV5171, UC3843, LM5181, perhaps TPS61170 or MIC2619, etc.).  The IC is at most a couple bucks; support components include resistors, capacitors and rectifiers, totaling about as much again.
The BOM cost might thus be well under $10 for the same function as $20-40 of DC-DC modules.
Cheaper sources than RECOM may be more competitive, but even so, it's hard to beat the bare cost of a flattened, integrated design.  (Note that RECOM excels in specialty products: their high voltage, low capacitance, standards-approved medical-grade modules for example.  These are even pricier, but getting your own circuit through approvals costs a heck of a lot more still, so there's a bigger demand for them.)
The above regards basic cost in small quantity.
Now also consider development cost, and production cost in quantity.
If production is small (hundreds, thousands per annum), design, logistic and administrative costs tend to dominate, and it's likely the product is high-margin, thus there is less pressure to cost-reduce the design.  Hiring an experienced engineer to optimize it, might cost more revenue than their improvements save in the immediate future.
Or, a product might be a minimum-viable initial design, created hastily to fill a market need; with an emphasis on time, using off-the-shelf modules like Power Integrations SCALE-2™ 2SP0115T2Ax-06 or Powerex VLA500-01 Hybrid IC IGBT Gate Driver + DC/DC Converter might gain that initial edge; it can then be optimized out of the design later.
Space
DC-DC modules require all the same support components, plus wasted space within the box, and volume spent on the box itself.  It can be taller, but you can also build your own sub-module that's vertically mounted, and convert even more horizontal footprint into vertical height.  Sometimes this helps, sometimes it doesn't; density will tend to disfavor packaged modules, in any case.
Complexity
It might seem like a lot to the novice, but it's simply standard practice in power electronics.  You need whatever bits and bobs make the thing go; sometimes that involves dozens of discrete transistors, other times a packaged module.
Complexity only modestly relates to design cost: an experienced engineer can copy-paste an existing design, be familiar with all the design considerations, and run through everything in a few days, or weeks.  A green engineer might struggle for months, or years even.
Anecdote:
Back when I started, out of college, I joined a company that had been toying with a new design industrial machine.  I don't know who all they had involved on it, but they left a few remnants with the project when we joined (i.e., myself and 2-3 coworkers were hired, around the same time, to work on the project).  Effects included some prototyped enclosures; a complicated transformer design (involving formed and brazed copper tubing); damaged power boards (fabricated on a standard quick-turn proto service); a few evaluation boards for signal generation and gate driving; and a small box of blown transistors bearing silent witness to our predecessors' past crimes (/s).  It was brought to my attention that these couple boxes of materials were the sum output of the past couple years of, I gathered, half-hearted effort to produce a new system.
After I joined, in the span of 1.5 years, I had led the hardware and control design into a comprehensive digital (software and FPGA) system, and had reliable operation of the prototype unit, scaled up to full specified power levels; and in 2.5 years, the product line was launched and my services were no longer required.
Now, for my part, I had already designed such a system entirely on my personal time -- it was still quite rough around the edges, but had all the important controls and protection.  "Green" is very relative here -- but to make the contrast that, one team (who may or may not have had much experience in electronic or power design, or much experience at all) had accomplished very little in several years, and another moved into production -- clearly there is some complexity involved.
Perhaps the previous team/members would've had more to show (or even found success!), if they had considered (or even been aware of?) modules like the above; or had concentrated on the fundamentals (power flow, power stage design, control concepts) rather than getting bogged down in the minutiae (blown transistors and boards).  These are tough topics to learn; some pick them up easier than others, certainly, but there's far too much to concentrate on if you are only looking at the design holistically -- how many components are involved, how do they connect, what values, etc.
Complexity is a matter of how easily we can break down a problem into constituent parts.  A design might contain a thousand components, but each collection of them is easy to understand: the function of the sub-sheets in your screenshots simply take a logic signal and convert it to another (transistor-scale) logic signal.  We abstract the gate driver into a concept, and it no longer matters that it contains one or a hundred components, just that it does what we want it to.
There is one remaining cost to complexity: very crudely speaking, the per-part cost of assembly might be $0.1 or so.  That's not to say the incremental cost of any part is the same: it costs a lot less to plonk down a dozen resistors of identical values, than it does a dozen unique ones.  Or the cost rises suddenly when a feeder/reel change is required.  And the cost of a dense, complex part (BGA chip, say) will be much more, given not just the time to position it on the board, and inspect the solder joints (usually via x-rays), but also the inevitable rework when the automated process fails.  The cost might be much less in overseas production, where labor costs are lower; and it can be reduced with automation, given enough production quantity to justify hooking up enough machines to run it.  (There are automated systems for surface mount pick-and-place; through-hole lead form and insert; wave or reflow soldering; and semi- and fully-automated visual and x-ray inspection systems.)

Love your answer AND the included anecdote -  really shows you care to answer the question and guide the questioner, as well as your thoughtfulness and expertise.

Thanks for the clear explanations! Got some useful insights
